# Is there a command to describe the language SQL (like \LaTeX for latex)?

Tags: macros

I like to use the command `\LaTeX` when I write about latex in a document. Is there a similiar command for SQL?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Usually, it is beste, to present a Minimal Working Example (MWE), to show, what you already have tried yourself.  Sometimes a sketch of the desired output is also helpful.

Comment: @Jan thank you for the warm welcome. Next time I will present an example.

Comment: ...I think it's normally just written out, like you've done it here. LaTeX has a fancy logo to show its typesetting power; SQL isn't anything like that. (Maybe it's all-caps because that's the *right* way to write it? :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to print SQL-code, than, there is a simple way to define a command for that task.  Just define the macro `\sql` in your preamble and use it in your document, wherever you like.  My simple suggestion:

```
 \newcommand{\sql}{\textbf{SQL}}
```

should do the trick, if you are aiming for a boldface SQL-sign.  If you want it with---say--- red color, try this

```
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\sql}{\textcolor{red}{SQL}}
```

Of course, you can combine color with font commands as shown above:

```
\newcommand{\sql}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{SQL}}}
```

Have fun.